# jQuery mouseenter / hover stop animation in vertical carousel loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loops, carousel

So i've built a really simple automatic vertical carousel that loops through a list of items, but now i need to stop the loop when the mouse enters the div, i've tried stop() but didn't work.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="relative pegascontainer">
<ul class='pegas'>
    <li>
        <div class="pega">
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="pega">
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="pega">
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="pega">
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my JS (190 is just the height of the container):

```
var listi = $(".pegas").children("li"),
    listiNum = (listi.length)/2,
    listiMax = (listiNum*190)-190;

function pegaLoop(){
    for (var i=0,len=listiNum; i<len; i++){

        $(".pegas").animate({
            'margin-top': -190*i
        }, 500, function(){
            if($(this).css("margin-top") == "-"+listiMax+"px"){
                $(this).animate({'margin-top': 0});
                pegaLoop();
            }
        }).delay(1000);

    }

};

pegaLoop();
```

I've tried things like this, but didn't work:

```
$(".pegas").hover(function() { 
        $('.pegas').stop();
    }, function() {
        pegaLoop();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `pegaLoop` is setting up *n* separate primary animations, where *n* is the number of `li` elements you have.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery isn't good at this out of the box. You might want to try a small [JQuery Pause Plugin](http://tobia.github.com/Pause/).

I understand this would let you write something like:

```
function pegaLoop()
{
   for (var i=0,len=listiNum; i<len; i++) // probably better as $("pegas li").each(...)
   {
       $(".pegas").animate({'margin-top': -190*i}, 500).delay(1000);
   }
   $(this).animate({'margin-top': 0}, pegaLoop);
}
```

Notice all this does is set up a queue of animations punctuated by delays that eventually recurs to the top, then enters all the animations in the queue again. We don't want to put `pegaLoop` in *every* callback, but only the very final one.

The pausing (with the plugin) would then be:

```
$(".pegas").hover(function()
 {
     $('.pegas').pause();
 },
 function()
 {
    $('.pegas').resume();
 });
```

Comment: That new refined function work perfectly, thanks you for that, but the Pause plugin didn't.